# SAML setup for Azure AD B2C vs Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0

I have to integrate a third party application for SAML authentication

The third party application provided their setup guide for Azure AD, but our application needs Azure AD B2C.

According to their guide, I have to add an enterprise application.

Since B2C does not have an enterprise application I added in "App Registration."

Next step is to add SAML configuration - Identifier (Entity ID), Reply URL (Assertion Consumer Service URL) , Sign-On URL, Relay State
For AD this setup is done directly on "Set Up SSO with SAML" screen.

But in B2C, I have to update the manifest file. Here, I am unsure where to add the Sign-On URL and Relay State.

Also, the integration requires me to download the metadata.xml file. How can I download it from B2C?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need an Enterprise Application.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?pivots=b2c-custom-policy&tabs=windows) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-saml?pivots=b2c-custom-policy&tabs=windows) will help you.

You need to use custom policies.

The metadata is here:

**Metadata**: Use the format:

```
https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/samlp/metadata
```

You don't configure the relayState.

The sign-on URL is generated from your application in SP mode. It has to contain an AuthnRequest.

[IDPInitiated](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-azure-ad-b2c-as-a-saml-idp-with-the-idp-initiated-flow-d80e76864474).

[SPInitiated](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-azure-ad-b2c-as-a-saml-idp-with-the-sp-initiated-flow-f4e34356635d).

Comment: https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/Samlp/metadata
This is the format, right? it is showing "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Also for Sign On Url the third party provided their own sign on url

Comment: Updated metadata - SO formatting!